# Unhandled exception occurred - System.IndexOutOfRangeException: upc

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I added a new table to our database named `upc`.

When I add it to the front end of our site, I'm getting this error:

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: upc

Source Error:

```
    if (!Sdr["upc"].ToString().Trim().Equals(""))

           liupc.InnerHtml = "upc: " + Sdr["upc"].ToString();

    else
```

I'm not sure what this error means or how I can resolve it - any insight is much appreciated.

Comment: What is Sdr? Could you provide some more code please?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing (you really need to show more code) that "Sdr" is a SqlDataReader instance.  If that's the case, you would not reference the table inside the indexer, but columns in the table (or whatever resultset) after a call to SqlCommand.ExecuteReader().

Something like:

```
SqlCommand cmd = ...;

SqlDataReader Sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while(Sdr.Read())
{
    var value = Sdr["column_name"];
    // etc...
}
```

Also, see [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, it isn't recognizing "upc" as a string index in your array `Sdr`.

Comment: How can i make upc recognizable?  is this something i do in the DB or add to my .cs file?  Sorry bout my lack of knowledge; complete first time working in this environment

Comment: Its hard to say without knowing what kind of array Sdr is. The array element must be defined before it can be used.

Comment: @aaron b Run your debugger and see what kinds of keys/values are inside Sdr. That should help you figure it out

Comment: @aaron b and yes, its in your .cs file, in your code. Within the scope of `Sdr`.. whatever it may be. I'm guessing its a DataRow?

Comment: not sure if this helps you guys: SqlDataReader Sdr;
        strQry = "uspListProductDetails @PRODUCTID =" + DID;
        Sdr = Connection.ExecuteReader(COS.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionText, strQry);
        Sdr.Read();
        if (Sdr.HasRows)
        {

Comment: lmao, yes that helps. As you call Sdr.Read() it will read in your result set row by row until it returns false (no more rows), and you access the _columns_ in the row with a string index: `Sdr["column1"]`

Comment: within that i have: if (Sdr.HasRows)
        {  
     if (!Sdr["upc"].ToString().Trim().Equals(""))
               liupc.InnerHtml = "upc: " + Sdr["upc"].ToString();
           else
               liupc.Visible = false;
        }
        Sdr.Close();
        Sdr.Dispose();
    }
}

Comment: That isn't how you implement a SqlDataReader. Please see seairth's answer. Its basically what I said in my last comment.

Answer (score 0):

change line 120 to be,

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Sdr["upc"]))
```

and try that.

Comment: Sdr is not a string array, unless he's converting it ToString() for no reason.

Comment: That is why I +1 your comment.

Comment: Just saying that will throw an error if Sdr["upc"] isn't of type string, which I'm pretty sure it isn't. I don't think you can even use string indexes for string arrays.